# Transact SQL - error when trying to perform an insert

Tags: t-sql, triggers

So my problem is that I get the following error after trying to perform an insert on my table that is called `Contrat`

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trig1, Line 137.
>
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I have a trigger set on the table that is triggered after an insert, when I disable the trigger, the insert works perfectly. I looked around and found that 'the trigger isn't programmed to handled multiple row return', I still can't figure out how to solve the isue.
This is the trigger:

```
create trigger trig1
on Contrat
after insert
as begin

declare @contrat int, @total money
set @contrat = (select inserted.numcontrat from inserted)
set @total = (select inserted.prix_mensuel * 12 from inserted)

update Ville
set Ville.total_ville = (select Ville.total_ville + @total from Ville)
from Contrat C, Bien_immobilier B, Quartier Q, Ville V
where C.code_bien = B.code_bien and B.code_Quartier = Q.code_quartier and Q.code_ville = V.code_ville and C.numcontrat = @contrat

end
```

the trigger is supposed to update a column in a different table named `Ville` after a row is inserted in `Contrat`, for that I need to go through four tables to reach it.

Let me know if any additional information is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) SQL Server triggers work per entire statement no row-by-row. So `set @contrat = (select inserted.numcontrat from inserted)` could not work if there is multiple insert 2)  `from Contrat C, Bien_immobilier B, Quartier Q, Ville V` use `JOIN` instead of old comma syntax 3) why `set Ville.total_ville = (select Ville.total_ville + @total from Ville)` ? Do you want **`set Ville.total_ville +=  @total`**?

Comment: For (3), yes, when a row is inserted in the table `Contrat`, the `total_ville` row in the table `Ville` will be updated where `@total` will be added to its original value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Apparently, the problem was with this line:
`set Ville.total_ville = (select Ville.total_ville + @total from Ville)`

So what it did is update the column `Ville.total_ville` with an entire table since the query `(select Ville.total_ville + @total from Ville)` returns a table because there is no condition filter applied.

To fix it, this is what I did:

```
create trigger trig1
on Contrat
after insert
as begin

declare @contrat int, @total money
set @contrat = (select inserted.numcontrat from inserted)
set @total = (select inserted.prix_mensuel * 12 from inserted)

update Ville
set Ville.total_ville = Ville.total_ville + @total
from Contrat C, Bien_immobilier B, Quartier Q
where C.code_bien = B.code_bien and B.code_Quartier = Q.code_quartier and Q.code_ville = Ville.code_ville and C.numcontrat = @contrat

end
```

Thank you very much for your help!